# Display HTTP Response Message in HTML using CGI (Python)

Tags: python, html, http, format, cgi

I have created a local server which sends a HTTP POST message to http://httpbin.org/post and then prints the return message on the screen.

The python CGI code that runs at the back end prints the return message in a 'pretty' format when run directly from the terminal:

```
Content-type:text/html


<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>
</head>
<body>
<h2>RETURN: </h2><h5>{
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, compress",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/1.2.0 CPython/2.7.3 Linux/3.5.0-17-generic",
    "Content-Length": "67"
  },
  "files": {},
  "origin": "125.63.99.141",
  "args": {},
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post",
  "data": "",
  "form": {
    "RAM": "2577.46",
    "TIME": "2013-05-20 21:36:16.388751",
    "TEMP": "+55.5\u00b0C"
  },
  "json": null
}</h5>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when the code is run through the local server using CGI, the message is badly formatted (all in one line):

```
 { "headers": { "Accept": "*/*", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Host": "httpbin.org", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, compress", "Content-Length": "60", "User-Agent": "python-requests/1.2.0 CPython/2.7.3 Linux/3.5.0-17-generic", "Connection": "close" }, "args": {}, "url": "http://httpbin.org/post", "data": "", "origin": "125.63.99.141", "form": { "TEMP": "+55.5", "TIME": "2013-05-20 21:57:38.973723", "RAM": "2478.78" }, "json": null, "files": {} }
```

I'm new to HTML and JSON but I think that there could be a way to store the response as a JSON object and then use some HTML tags to print it in a formatted manner.

This is my CGI file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests 
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime

# script to extract free RAM from vmstat
str = "vmstat | awk '/[0-9]/ { print $4/1024 }'"

# script to extract CPU core temp from sensors
temp = "sensors | grep temp | awk '{print $2}'"

# run script and store output
p=subprocess.Popen(str, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()

p=subprocess.Popen(temp, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out2, err2 = p.communicate()

# create dataload 
ram = out.rstrip()
time = datetime.now()
temp = out2.rstrip()

payload = {'RAM':ram, 'TEMP':temp, 'TIME':time}
#print payload

# send HTTP POST request 
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=payload)

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>TEST</title>"
print "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>" 
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>RETURN: %s</h2>" % (r.text)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than wrapping the output in `<h2>`, wrap it in `<pre>`.  That will keep your newlines intact.